# JDBC SQL SELECT query sum method not behaving properly

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hi I have a table with item and price as shown below

```
 item    price
 ABC      5.0
 DEF      6.0
```

and I am trying to execute it with the following query.

```
select sum(sign(price)*ceiling(abs(price))) as price, item from product
```

Now when I execute this query staight away in the following way it works shows total as 11.0 in output for both item

```
statement.exectuteQuery("select sum(sign(price)*ceiling(abs(price))) as price, item from product")
```

But when I put query in string strangely it does not work and it gives null as output in price column

```
String qry = "select sum(sign(price)*ceiling(abs(price))) as price, item from product";
statement.exectuteQuery(qry);
```

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions that you might be catching and returning null instead?

Comment: no exception it just null in the output table

Comment: just curious, which DBMS allows queries like this, mixing aggregated and not aggregated columns?

Comment: @user1455836: probably MySQL: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(sign(price)*ceiling(abs(price))) as price, item
from product
group by item
```

The aggregate functions such as `sum` and `count` will do the entire table, if not using a `GROUP BY`.

Concerning the error: it is the first time I see the keyword `table` there. Try it as mentioned.